# Android Listview reset changes when scroll

Tags: android, listview, savechanges

I'm using a **ListFragment** with a custom Adapter.

My adapter have a `textview` and a hide `imageview` with a arrow. When user select a item, the arrows shows up and the background color change. But, when user scroll the list, all the changes get back to default.

What I should do to fix the changes?

EDIT:

my Adapter class..

```
public class PropriedadeAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private List<Propriedades> prop;

public PropriedadeAdapter(Context context, List<Propriedades> prop) {
    this.context = context;
    this.prop = prop;
}

public int getCount() {
    return prop.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return prop.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Recupera o produto da posição atual
    Propriedades p = prop.get(position);

    // Layout XML
    int arquivoLayout = R.layout.lista_prop;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(arquivoLayout, null);

    // Atualiza o valor do Text para o nome do produto
    TextView textNome = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nome);
    textNome.setText(p.getNome());

    return v;
}
}
```

my Fragment class..

```
public class frag_lista extends ListFragment{

ImageView ultimoItem = null;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
     ArrayList<Propriedades> props = new ArrayList<Propriedades>();
    for(int i = 0; i <50; i++)
    {
        Propriedades prop = new Propriedades();
        prop.setNome("FRUTA "+i);
        props.add(prop);
    }
    setListAdapter(new PropriedadeAdapter(this.getActivity(),props));
}


@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    ImageView seta = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imgSeta);
    seta.setVisibility(0);
    LinearLayout linha = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.linha);
    linha.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    if(ultimoItem != null)
    {
        ultimoItem.setVisibility(4);
    }
    ultimoItem = seta;
}   

}
```

what i should do to persiste the changes of onListItemClick method????

Comment: When you say "the changes get back to default", is it only for views that appears (i.e. views that are not currently shown when you start scrolling) ?

Comment: i.e. My listview have 120 itens (default state = bgcolor green and no arrow). If I select the first one (bgcolor = red with a arrow) then scroll to the last, when i get back to the first, all the changes get back to the original state.

Answer (score 2):

convertView has two states where it is null and not null. Your issue happens because eveytime yout getView() calls a new layout inflater instance is initializing.
Initialize the inflater only when the convertView is null.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Propriedades p = prop.get(position); 
    int arquivoLayout = R.layout.lista_prop;

    View v;

    if (convertView==null){
        v = inflater.inflate(arquivoLayout, null);
    }
    else {
        v = convertView;
    }  

    // Atualiza o valor do Text para o nome do produto
    TextView textNome = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nome);
    textNome.setText(p.getNome());

    return v;
}
```

Also, remember to declare inflater as a field.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = null;
```

And to initialize it in the constructor.

```
public PropriedadeAdapter(Context context, List<Propriedades> prop) {
    this.context = context;
    this.prop = prop;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, I think you don't use the Adapter correctly.

An [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) provides methods that are automatically called by the ListView.

You should keep selected indexes in memory and restore the View state each time the [getView(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) method is called (jusging from the position argument).

Look for tutorial about ListView and Adapter.

**EDIT:**

Note that I have not test the code but it could be something like this:

```
// TeddyBearFr: Class name typically starts with a capital letter! Frag_lista, not frag_lista
public class frag_lista extends ListFragment{

    ImageView ultimoItem = null;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
         ArrayList<Propriedades> props = new ArrayList<Propriedades>();
        for(int i = 0; i <50; i++)
        {
            Propriedades prop = new Propriedades();
            prop.setNome("FRUTA "+i);
            props.add(prop);
        }
        setListAdapter(new PropriedadeAdapter(this.getActivity(),props));
    }


    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        // TeddyBearFr: notify the adapter
        ( (PropriedadeAdapter) this.getListAdapter() ).onListItemClick(position);

        // TeddyBearFr: your last item must be managed in the getView(...) method of the Adapter
        //if(ultimoItem != null)
        //{
        //  ultimoItem.setVisibility(4);    // TeddyBearFr: don't use integer like this, use Android constants! View.INVISIBLE
        //}
        //ultimoItem = seta;
    }   

}


public class PropriedadeAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private final static String TAG = "PropriedadeAdapter";
    private Context context;
    private List<Propriedades> prop;
    private Set<Integer> mSelectedItemsPosition;

    public PropriedadeAdapter(Context context, List<Propriedades> prop) {
        this.context = context;
        this.prop = prop;
        // TeddyBearFr: set to store selected indexes
        this.mSelectedItemsPosition = new HashSet<Integer>();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return prop.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return prop.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "getView(position=" + position + ", convertView=" + convertView + ", parent=" + parent + ")" );

        // Recupera o produto da posição atual
        Propriedades p = prop.get(position);

        // TeddyBearFr: use existing view if exist ; otherwise create a new one
        View v;
        if( convertView == null ){
            // Layout XML
            int arquivoLayout = R.layout.lista_prop;
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(arquivoLayout, null);
        }
        else{
            v = convertView;
        }

        // Atualiza o valor do Text para o nome do produto
        TextView textNome = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nome);
        textNome.setText(p.getNome());

        // TeddyBearFr: update view according its selection state
        ImageView seta = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imgSeta);
        boolean isViewSelected = this.mSelectedItemsPosition.contains(position);
        int visibility = ( isViewSelected ? VIEW.VISIBLE : VIEW.GONE );
        seta.setVisibility(visibility);

        LinearLayout linha = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.linha);
        linha.setBackgroundColor( isViewSelected ? Color.GRAY : Color.RED );

        if( position == getCount()-1 ){
            // perform special processes on the last item of the list if needed
        }

        return v;
    }

    // TeddyBearFr: callback when click
    public void onListItemClick(int position){
        Log.d(TAG, "onListItemClick(position=" + position + ")");

        // update selected index data
        // Note that I haven't tested if it works. Because native integer "position" will be wrapped in Integer object, there's a chance that the Set compares the references on objects instead of their value
        if( this.mSelectedItemsPosition.contains(position) ){
            this.mSelectedItemsPosition.remove(position);
        }
        else{
            this.mSelectedItemsPosition.add(position);
        }

        // ask the list to be refreshed -> you'll see that getView() will be called only for each displayed view
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Comment: i have edited my question, can you show me what i'm doing wrong?